# Is there any way to restrict the types of files users can store in my app using iTunes File Sharing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, ipod

See the title. If my app is a sound recording app with iTunes File Sharing, I obviously don't want people storing TXT, HTMl, etc. files in my app with iTunes File Sharing. Is there any way to restrict this to just CAF and MP3? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. All you can do is check for files with the wrong type and either remove them (bad—deleting users’ files without warning is liable to piss them off), ignore them (okay), or warn users that your app can’t handle whatever they’re trying to do (best).